# Add and Package files in MSI using TFS build

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, windows-installer, setup-deployment, build-definition

I have multiple build definitions which generate certain output files and place them in a staging area. Another build definition needs to pick up these files and package them into an MSI using SetUp project of visual studio installer project.

I am unable to find a way to do this in tfs builds which will build the setup project by dynamically adding latest files and generate an MSI.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to build the multiple artifacts in **Release** instead of another build definition.

Assuming you are using TFVC. You need to set the trigger order for the multiple build definitions, assume your have 3 build definitions A, B, C. The last completed is **C**， then you can trigger the release by **C**)

1. Create a Continuous Deployment Release Definition
2. TFS 2017 : You can link the TFVC repository as the Primary artifact
   source
3. TFS 2015 : You need to create another build definition to copy the
   source of the SetUp project.
4. Link **each** build definition as the Artifact Source
5. Select the last completed build definition (**C**) to trigger the Release
   (Triggers > Continuous Deployment > **Set trigger on artifact source** )
6. Add **build task** in Release definition to build the setup project.

For Building Setup Projects you can reference below articles:

- http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/building-vs-2015-setup-projects-in-team-build
- https://vikas15bhardwaj.wordpress.com/2016/09/18/part-3-create-tfs-build-definition/

[image]

Comment: @Saurav Maiti Have you resolved your issue by above workaround? any update for this?